# Retrieve count of SelectList items?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

**Problem: I can't access the count of items in a `SelectList`**

I have an HtmlHelper method that returns a SelectList:

```
public static SelectList FilterSelectList(this HtmlHelper helper, List<Stuff> eList, string dept)
{
 List<Stuff> returnList = new List<Stuff>();

 //Do Stuff    

 return new SelectList(returnList, "ID", "Name");
}
```

I then have a test which confirms that the filter was done correctly:

```
// Arrange
List<Stuff> eList = MVCMocks.GetList();
string dept = "T";
int expectedCount = eList.FindAll(e => e.Dept == dept).Count;

// Act
var actual = HtmlHelpers.FilterSelectList(helper, eList, dept);

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actual.Count, "The list was not properly filtered.");
```

Calling `actual.Count` results in an error.

I'm hoping this is just a case of me having a stupid oversight, but I've been banging my head on this for a while.  Prove me right! :)

**EDIT: Stuff I've Tried**

```
actual.Count
actual.Count()
actual.Items.Count()
actual.GetEnumerator().?
```

Comment: What error does actual.Count produce?

Comment: System.Web.Mvc.SelectList does not contain a definition for 'Count', and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument...etc etc etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `actual.Count()` (note parens!) not `actual.Count`.

Comment: Then you don't have a `using System.Linq` in your test class.

Comment: Aha! That did it! Thanks Craig :)